# protocol error setting up virtualenvironment through vagrant on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, vagrant

I'm trying to set up a virtualenv on Ubuntu 12.04 with Python 2.7 using vagrant but having same issues. it seems like this issues is seen only when "vagrant up" is issued from windows. what is the solution? any pointers?

```
New python executable in .vagrant-env/bin/python
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.11.6', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 984, in   create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1404, in install_python
    os.symlink(py_executable_base, full_pth)
   OSError: [Errno 71] Protocol error
```

Comment: seems like its related to this .. but i can't find the answer to solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907359/problem-setting-up-a-virtualenv/24637484#24637484

Comment: Has anybody tried solving it with pythonbrew? if so how ?

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 34):

The solution is to use `--always-copy`. See [here](https://github.com/gratipay/gratipay.com/issues/2327) for the gory details.

Answer (score 19):

This error can be fixed if you create the virtual env outside the /vagrant/ shared folder...

If go to the home folder of your vagrant user, you can create the virtualenv in there without this problem!

Just the venv must be out of this /vagrant/ directory... after that you can go work as usually activating this venv and working with your sorce code in the usual /vagrat/ shared dir...

Answer (score 18):

I found the issue and fixed it. Just start your git bash/cmd prompt console as an administrator. Then, vagrant up > setup your virtual env. It should be a cake walk.

Thanks
Venkat

Comment: This is the root of the problem.

Comment: (sorry for the bumping of a 6-year-old post)
I believe this is also the solution for other ways to setup a venv (notably `python3 -m venv venv`)

Answer (score 3):

Use this

`virtualenv --python= <#Python path for specific version#>  <#Folder name#> --always-copy`

Example:

`virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7 venv --always-copy`

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. Just restarting the vagrant box was enough to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
virtualenv venv --python=python3
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

`sudo virtualenv venv`