# Cloning a heroku hosted django project to your local machine

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm new to python, Django, heroku and even PostgreSQL but am working on a Django project with a team of 3 devs (they set it up), so I'm trying to set it up on my local machine so I can start developing.

Firstly I cloned the repository to my local machine, there was a `requirement.txt` file, so I ran `pip install -r ./requirements.txt` to install all the python packages the project uses. Theres a `runtime.txt` file which specifies `python 3.5` so I need to upgrade that. I see that `gunicorn` is one of the packages in `requiments.txt`, so I'm guessing I need to use that as the web server.

Heres the packages in `requirements.txt` that look important to me:

```
Django==1.9.6
gunicorn==19.5.0
psycopg2==2.6.1
boto3==1.3.1
boto==2.40.0
whitenoise==3.2
django-extensions==1.6.7
```

The site also has a `.buildpacks` file, which seems to be a heroku specific thing:

```
https://github.com/a2ikm/heroku-buildpack-libjpeg62
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
https://github.com/rafaelp/heroku-buildpack-wkhtmltopdf
```

Theres a Procfile that contains this:

```
web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi --log-file -
worker: celery worker --app=genome.tasks.app -l info --beat
```

I'm wondering what the best way to do this is. Is there a way to automatically generate a virtual environment that has all the requirements and software specified in the project? I'm already using a virtual dev environment with created with Vagrant so I could provision it with all the dependencies, but I get the feeling theres a better way to do this.

UPDATE:
Heres what what happens when I try to run the server with `python manage.py runserver`:

```
$ python manage.py runserver

Current environment: P


Current environment: P

Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fd0d08c71b8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/var/www/sd2/selfdecode/decodify/urls.py", line 30, in <module>
    url(r'', include("genome.urls")),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/var/www/sd2/selfdecode/genome/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/var/www/sd2/selfdecode/genome/views.py", line 20, in <module>
    from decodify.aggregators import ArrayAgg, JsonAgg, ArrayaAggDelimited
  File "/var/www/sd2/selfdecode/decodify/aggregators.py", line 29
    def __init__(self, *expressions, distinct=False, **extra):
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm guessing the parse error is due to using `python 2.7` in a project that uses `python 3.5`. I installed python 3.5 with sudo apt-get install `python3-all`. Trying the same thing with `python3`:

```
    $ python3 manage.py runserver
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    ImportError: No module named 'django'

    > python3
```

The second error means the packages I installed with `pip install requirements.txt`, they were installed for python 2.7, not 3.5. So this is obviously where virtual environments can come in. I tried this `sudo -H virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 py3env`, both with and without sudo, and both times I got errors :

```
[06:08 PM]-[vagrant@machine1]-[/var/www/sd2/selfdecode]-[git master]
$ sudo -H virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 py3env
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /var/www/sd2/selfdecode/py3env/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /var/www/sd2/selfdecode/py3env/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2328, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 925, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1370, in install_python
    os.symlink(py_executable_base, full_pth)
OSError: [Errno 71] Protocol error: 'python3' -> '/var/www/sd2/myproj/py3env/bin/python'
```

I came across this thread:
[protocol error setting up virtualenvironment through vagrant on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640819/protocol-error-setting-up-virtualenvironment-through-vagrant-on-ubuntu)

Where someone was having this problem using `virtualenv` inside a vagrant VM, and a possible solution is setting up the venv outside of the shared vagrant folder.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. That pip command *is* how you install ask the dependencies.

Comment: But then theres all the additional dependencies like python3.5, postgresql, nginx server (I assume I need that since it uses gunicorn).

Comment: You don't need gunicorn or nginx in development, you use the built-in dev server.

Comment: @HorseO'Houlihan, there are some step's that you need to follow so you can start your app on Heroku, [THIS](https://realpython.com/blog/python/migrating-your-django-project-to-heroku/) is one of the many tutorial's that can help you understand what you need to do

Comment: I'm not trying to set it up on heroku, thats already done, the other devs in my team have building this site for months now. I need to do the opposite, get the heroku project onto my local machine so I can start development.