# OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: virtualenv on python.

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am working on window 10 os. I use vagrant for my python environment. 
But when I try to create new virtualenv in sychronized folder between Window and vagrant. I always get errors:

```
[vagrant@localhost develop]$ virtualenv --no-site-packages -vvv labEnv
Creating labEnv/lib/python2.7
Symlinking Python bootstrap modules
  Symlinking labEnv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
  Symlinking labEnv/lib/python2.7/config
  Symlinking labEnv/lib/python2.7/os.py
  Ignoring built-in bootstrap module: posix
  Symlinking labEnv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
  Cannot import bootstrap module: nt
  Symlinking labEnv/lib/python2.7/ntpath.py
  Symlinking labEnv/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
  Symlinking labEnv/lib/python2.7/fnmatch.py
  Symlinking labEnv/lib/python2.7/locale.py
  Symlinking labEnv/lib/python2.7/encodings
  Symlinking labEnv/lib/python2.7/codecs.py
  Symlinking labEnv/lib/python2.7/stat.py
  Symlinking labEnv/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
  Creating parent directories for labEnv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 984, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1180, in install_python
    copy_required_modules(home_dir, symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1119, in copy_required_modules
    copyfile(filename, dst_filename, symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 467, in copyfile
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'labEnv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload'
```

But when I try to create virtualenv in other folder except sychronized folder. it's ok.

Comment: See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15768760/2744166

Comment: I don't know vagrant well, but perhaps this can help shed some light:  http://blog.rudylee.com/2014/10/27/symbolic-links-with-vagrant-windows/

Comment: I think this is my problem "The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of default". I reinstalled the guest additions. I think if you meet issue with sharing folder. The first of all you should think about the guest additions. Because this additions take care about sharing folder feature.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you have created this virtualenv before. Try `workon [name of project]` and see if it's able to switch to it. You can simply type `workon` to view available virtual envs.