# [Python]Fail to create virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, virtualenv

I was trying to create a virtualenv on my vagrant centos7 with python3 and the following happens. Is there anything I can do with it? The version of virtualenv is 13.1.2 and python is 3.5.1. Thanks.

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr/local'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2363, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 832, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 994, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1192, in install_python
    copy_required_modules(home_dir, symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1131, in copy_required_modules
    copyfile(filename, dst_filename, symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 468, in copyfile
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'venv/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload'
```

Comment: It looks like you already have a (possibly broken) virtualenv `venv` in that directory, and virtualenv doesn't overwrite existing files by default. Try removing it (`rm -rf venv`) and running the creation command again,  or using the [`--clear`](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#cmdoption--clear) switch for virtualenv.

Comment: I tried to delete and create the venv a few times and it is still not working even with the --clear. Is there any way to fix the broken virtualenv? I tried to reinstall it with pip but not working too. Or I should just reinstall the whole centos to save the time.

Comment: If you are trying to create the virtualenv inside a synced folder, it might be a problem with symlinks not being created correctly, as in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907359/problem-setting-up-a-virtualenv) question.

Comment: yes, it works fine if not in the shared folder. Even though it is the perfect solution, I will just build the venv outside of the shared folder. However, I find another problem when trying to install djangocms-installer(setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution
) but it is a different problem so I will consider this problem as solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably the problems with symbolic link at shared folder. I solved it by simply create the `venv` outside of the shared folder.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have already a venv, try to delete it with

```
rm -rf yourPath/venv
```

and for create a new one

```
python3 -m venv pathToCreateNewVenv
```